# Caffe: How to get `solver.prototxt` parameters by code?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I want to access the `solver.prototxt` parameters such as `base_lr` (Base Learning Rate) or `weight_decay` from python code.

is there any way to access these from the `solver.net` object ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb), you can access it by :

```
### define solver
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
s = caffe_pb2.SolverParameter()

# Set a seed for reproducible experiments:
# this controls for randomization in training.
s.random_seed = 0xCAFFE

# Specify locations of the train and (maybe) test networks.
s.train_net = train_net_path
s.test_net.append(test_net_path)
s.test_interval = 500  # Test after every 500 training iterations.
s.test_iter.append(100) # Test on 100 batches each time we test.

s.max_iter = 10000     # no. of times to update the net (training iterations)

# EDIT HERE to try different solvers
# solver types include "SGD", "Adam", and "Nesterov" among others.
s.type = "SGD"
# Set the initial learning rate for SGD.
s.base_lr = 0.01  # EDIT HERE to try different learning rates
```

etc.