# How to manually set net and other parameters for a solver in caffe python programming?

Tags: python, caffe

With the content of solver.prototxt as the following:

```
test_iter: 2
test_interval: 50
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100
display: 20
max_iter: 500
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.005
solver_mode: CPU
```

I tried the following code in caffe:

```
solver = caffe.SGDSolver('< some long path >/solver.prototxt')
solver.net = < some code created net >
solver.solve()
```

I got the following error:

...
[ ... solver.cpp:67] Check failed: num_train_nets >= 1 (0 vs. 1) SolverParameter must specify a train net using one of these fields: net, net_param, train_net, train_net_param
*** Check failure stack trace: ***

I wonder if there is a possible way to manually set the parameters of a solver by python code not by only load a prototxt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pycaffe, but according to your error, I think you are just missing a train net in your solver.prototxt. Add a line like this :

```
train_net: "path/to/your/train.prototxt"
```

and it should be ok.

I don't know what version of caffe you have but in the current one, the error should be (same line in [solver.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp), close content) :

```
CHECK_GE(num_train_nets, 1) << "SolverParameter must specify a train net "
<< "using one of these fields: " << field_names;
```

which makes the error simpler to identify.

Comment: Yes. That could be easy. But is there a possible way to manually set the parameters of a solver by python code not by only load a prototxt file?

Comment: Ok, then I think it is a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026431/caffe-how-to-get-solver-prototxt-parameters-by-code/44678975#44678975) which I just answered. I have not tested the solution, please tell me if it really solves the problem.

Comment: The answer is impossible. I see.